# How to get instance of class without creating a new empty instance

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a class called MyClass. MyClass is using SceneKit and on sceneDidLoad() is adding a sprite to my sks with this class attached:

```
class MyClass: SKScene{
   var s = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myImage.png"); 

   override func sceneDidLoad() {
      s.name = "TheNamedInstanceWithMySprite"
      s.size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10);
      self.addChild(s)
      print("is created!");
   }

   func DoSomething(){
      print(s.name);
   }

}
```

Now in my interface controller I want to get a reference to this instance of the class of the 's' object. That will allow me to call the DoSomething function directly for that specific sprite to change...

A problem - in my interface controller script - when I declare my variable it creates a new instance of it. Is there any way to declare without creating a new instance:

```
//problem - creates a new empty instance of the class on declaration
var mySprite = MyClass()

@IBOutlet weak var spriteTapGestures: WKTapGestureRecognizer!

@IBAction func onSpriteTap(_ sender: Any) {
   mySprite.DoSomething()
}
```

In my interface controller I can find and set the correct instance of my sprite/class to my global variable in awake

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
   if let foundVar = MySceneClass(fileNamed: "MyClass") {
      mySprite = foundVar
   }
}
```

After awake() is called with the assignment of the found class - I can call DoSomething with the correct console log... But it's annoying that in order to create a global variable of 'mySprite' that I need to initialize it with an empty MyClass() which in-turn calls 'print("is created!");'

I'm new to swift, but it seems there's got to be a better way. How can I create a global variable in my interface controller without creating an empty instance of it. How can I go directly and assign it to my existing instance and have it as a global var in my interface controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
var title: String?
```

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-lazy-property-initialization/

basically just need to declare it as an optional var so it starts out as nil... allows me to assign it's type without initializing it.